# HereMaps API Autosuggest results for resultType houseNumber returns only label

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest, heremaps

Using HereMaps api autosuggest for resultType houseNumber retuerns only label in address property. 'Till tomorrow it used to return countryCode, countryName, state, county, city, district, street, postalCode and houseNumber.
Is there any change to response?

EDIT: api call

[https://autosuggest.search.hereapi.com/v1/autosuggest?app_id=${app_id}&apiKey=${apiKey}&at=44.8154033,20.2825135&q=koste%20glavinica%2016&lang=%27en%27](https://autosuggest.search.hereapi.com/v1/autosuggest?app_id=$%7Bapp_id%7D&apiKey=$%7BapiKey%7D&at=44.8154033,20.2825135&q=koste%20glavinica%2016&lang=%27en%27)

Response used to be like this:

```
address: {
     label: "ШАРАН, Кеј ослобођења 53, 11210 Београд, Србија",
     countryCode: "SRB",
     countryName: "Србија",
     state: "Централна Србија",
     county: "Град Београд",
     city: "Београд",
     district: "Земун",
     street: "Кеј ослобођења",
     postalCode: "11210",
     houseNumber: "53",
},
```

And now response is:

```
"address": {
      "label": "ШАРАН, Кеј ослобођења 53, 11210 Београд, Србија"
},
```

Comment: It looks very strange. you might have changed something. Please consider showing your code.

Comment: @ShoaibK. i edited question. Api call is below EDIT.
Well, this was stable till yesterday, after noon. 
Thnx for reply

Comment: I am looking into this.

Comment: Internal ticket has been raised for other similar SO question. fyi @leopectus

Comment: Thnx for swift reply

Comment: hi @HEREDeveloperSupport any news from the team? We're still getting only a label instead of full address info.

Answer (score 3):

Please add "show=details" to your API call to get the full address back.

As our Geocoder and Search product is still under active development, please "NOTE: The response may contain experimental elements not documented here. Any undocumented element is subject to removal at any time."

Comment: thanks! does that mean that v7 is not production ready? for v6 REST API we saw that is in maintenance mode.

Comment: V7 is production ready.  New features will continue add to v7. For v6 only critical bugs will be fixed, but no more feature improvement.

Comment: I tried this on https://revgeocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/revgeocode and https://lookup.search.hereapi.com/v1/lookup and it gave me an error, saying "Unsupported value 'details'".